# Is there a way to access the columns/rows returned by a PROFILE query?

Tags: memgraphdb

Is there a way to access the columns/rows returned by a PROFILE query? So for example, only return the absolute time (something like `RETURN absolute_time`) from a specific operator (`WHERE operator LIKE 'ScanALL (n)'`)?
I'd like to track the runtime of the _online algos (f.e `pagerank_online.update(createdVertices, createdEdges)`) with increasing size of the graph. The best way of doing this seems to Create the trigger with the `PROFILE` call instead of the "real" execution call of the pagerank_algo. But I would need to save the result somewhere.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately you can't do that. You see the `PROFILE` clause is used to analyze the execution plan of a query and doesn't behave like an usual clause that would return results.